# trouble unit testing reactive form fields in angular

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, unit-testing, angular

I'm learning Angular 2 and unit testing using @angular/cli 1.0.0-beta.30 and had a bit of success testing one aspect of a form field's validity, but not all. I'm using an inline template in my component for the time being to remove a layer of complexity for now (a form template in a separate file introduces asynchronicity, correct?).

The `ngOnInit()` defines a `name` property  that includes the validators for "required" and "minLength". Currently an empty form field will correctly trigger the "required" validator but not the "minLength" validator. The `name.errors` array in the test does not contain any reference to required at all, `name.errors['minLength']` returns `undefined`. Does minLength need to be handled asynchronously? I'm having trouble finding docs or examples that fit my problem.

```
// signup-form.component.ts
...
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {

    user: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
            account: this.fb.group({
                email: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")],
                confirm: ['', Validators.required]
            })
        })
    }

    onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: User, valid: boolean }) {
        console.log(value, valid);
    }

}
```

**My test**

```
// signup-form.component.spec.ts
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form.component';

describe('SignupFormComponent', () => {
    let component: SignupFormComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignupFormComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SignupFormComponent],
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignupFormComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('form invalid when empty', () => {
        expect(component.user.valid).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('name field validity', () => {
        let name = component.user.controls['name'];
        expect(name.valid).toBeFalsy();

        let errors = {};
        name.setValue("");
        errors = name.errors || {};
        expect(errors['required']).toBeTruthy(); // this works
        expect(errors['minLength']).toBeTruthy(); // this fails, "undefined"
    });

});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answering your question

> The name.errors['minLength'] returns undefined, Does minLength need to be
>   handled asynchronously?

You can just check the form for a specific error

```
expect(form.control.hasError('emailInvalid', ['email'])).toBe(true);
```

Below is a complete test

```
// signup-form.component.spec.ts
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form.component';

describe('SignupFormComponent', () => {
    let component: SignupFormComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignupFormComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SignupFormComponent],
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignupFormComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('form invalid when empty', () => {
        expect(component.user.valid).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('name field validity', () => {
        let name = component.user.controls['name'];
        expect(name.valid).toBeFalsy();

        name.setValue("");
        expect(name.hasError('required')).toBeTruthy();

        name.setValue("A");
        expect(name.hasError('minLength')).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
expect(name.hasError('minlength', ['minlength'])).toEqual(false);
```

Try this it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the validation key you're looking for is "minlength" non-camelCase, note the lower-case "l". I have personally run into this oddly named error property.

Answer (score 0):

**'minLength'** is handled in the same way as 'required' or any of the other Validators (e.g. maxLength, pattern).

Unless your signup-form.component.ts code is truncated, I believe that you are missing a couple of things.

Inside your FormBuilder, you need to subscribe to data changes.
`this.user.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));`

Then you need to declare the onValueChanged function. Consult the [Angular Form Validation cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html) for a generic onValueChanged function.

You'll also need to populate the formErrors object with the appropriate keys.

```
formErrors = {
  'name': ''
 }
```

And supply validationMessages.

```
validationMessages = {
  'name': {
    'required': 'Name is required.',
    'minlength': 'Name must be at least 2 characters long.'
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(errors['minlength']).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to Validator.required priority, when such error exists - other validators are not even invoked and does not produce other errors. You need to set some incorrect value for testing that specific part :)